# Change encoding and extension of files within a directory using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, loops

I've been trying to write a script to change the file encoding and file extension for a group of files within a specific directory to no avail. So far the get-content and set-content method has been working, but only for individual files (haven't gotten it to loop).

i.e

```
get-content testdocument.txt | set-content -encoding utf8 "testdocument.xml" 
#works!
```

i.e.

```
$a = dir |
    $a foreach-object |
        get-content | set-content -encoding utf8 $a_fullname.xml
#doesn't work =(
```

I've also had success (limited) with the rename-item cmdlet. I'm able to rename all the items within a directory, but am unable to change the encoding.

i.e

```
get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '.txt','.xml'} 
#works!
```

i.e

```
get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '.txt','.xml'} | -encoding utf8
#doesn't work =(
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I apologize if this question seems trivial (new to Powershell/scripting in general, also first time posting). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your loop, you need to modularize your commands to where you can reference them and call them properly.  In your case, rather than calling the "fullName" property, you need to be calling "baseName" and appending ".xml" to it in your original command that works.  After that, simply using the right variables in the right places in your ForEach loop will make it work.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem
ForEach ($item in $a) {
  Get-Content $item.FullName | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 "$($item.Basename).xml"
}
```

This will allow you to have your original files next to your new xml files with the appropriate encoding.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much Bryce for the help, and the great explanation. Hope you have a great week!

Comment: Thanks @MrShakur and you too.  If you wouldn't mind marking the answer as correct (and upvoting it, if you have the permissions to) I'd appreciate it.  There should be a green check image to the left of the answer's score.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 to fix that all we'd have to do is put the Path on the tail end of the `$a = Get-ChildItem` line

Comment: That's not why it won't work.  You're referencing `$item.BaseName` and if it doesn't have a fully-qualified path, it'll use `$pwd`

Answer (score 0):

To address your questions, you're using the wrong syntax for most of your commands.  I would suggest looking at `Get-Command -Name Get-Help -Syntax` and `Get-Help -Name Get-Command` (replace `-Name` with the cmdlet you're using).

1. `Rename-Item` is only intended to rename.. items.  It does not change encoding.
2. `ForEach-Object` is used for two reasons, to iterate over a collection and get the value of a member, or to perform an action per item.  In your case:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\myfiles' |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Wrapping in parens prevents filelocking
        (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName) |
            Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8
        Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName).xml" -Path $_.FullName
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for additional insight @theIncorrigible1. I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I'll do some homework on how to use proper syntax, so as to understand things better for the future. Take care!